# Return a variable from sql query in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have MySQL query in Node.js where I'm trying to return "variable" and assign in to getVarible OUTSIDE my query. Is it possible to do in this case? If so, how?

Here is my code :

```
var sqlQuery = connection.query(result, function(err, rows, fields) {
        var count = rows.length;
        if(count === 1){
            var variable = rows[0].item;
            return variable;
        }            
    }
});

var getVariable = variable;
```

Comment: `var getVariable = sqlQuery` sqlQuery already has the value of variable, since thats what you return/assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare getVariable before your query call, you should be able to access it once your query return, within your cacllback fuction. You can try something like this:

```
var getVariable = {};

var sqlQuery = connection.query(result, function(err, rows, fields) {
        var count = rows.length;
        if(count === 1){
            getVariable = rows[0].item;
        }            
    }
});
```

However keep in mind that query execution is asynchronous, so your variable will be empty until your callback is executed.

So I would suggest you all logic where you use that variable to be executed within callback or use a promise of async framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your `connection.query` does not return what you think it returns i.e. `return variable;` statement has no effect.

Checkout the API with the usage of query object.

```
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM posts');
query
  .on('error', function(err) {
    // Handle error, an 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
  })
  .on('fields', function(fields) {
    // the field packets for the rows to follow
  })
  .on('result', function(row) {
    // Pausing the connnection is useful if your processing involves I/O
    connection.pause();

    processRow(row, function() {
      connection.resume();
    });
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // all rows have been received
  });
```

Alternatively you can have a short hand to handle the success, error by using the second parameter to `connection.query`. This is a function with signature `function (error, results, fields)` which does the same thing as above API.

`connection.query(sqlQueryStr, function (error, results, fields) {})`

The call to `connection.query` is asynchronous and the function passed as the second argument is executed only after the results are available i.e the query has executed.